# Strange Offset in Apache Superset time selection - can this be fixed with some sort of timezone setting?

Tags: apache-superset

I experience a strange issue where my data is in UTC and the data picker selects time by a large offset. I'd like the UI to select UTC time only.

In the documentation it states Superset is build to run on UTC time only. I also found some threads one can change this by setting the Linux environment via ENV variable to other timezone:

```
ENV TZ Europe/Amsterdam
RUN ln -snf /usr/share/zoneinfo/$TZ /etc/localtime && echo $TZ > /etc/timezone
```

**Wrong behaviour (UTC is approx 17h December 22nd):**

(same behaviour in all dashboards)

[image]

**Query behind this data (I used "view query in SQLLab")**

```
SELECT toDateTime(intDiv(toUInt32(toDateTime(delivery_date)), 300)*300) AS __timestamp,
       COUNT(*) AS count
FROM spearad_data.a_performance_view
WHERE delivery_date >= toDateTime('2020-12-21 23:00:00')
  AND delivery_date < toDateTime('2020-12-22 00:00:00')
GROUP BY toDateTime(intDiv(toUInt32(toDateTime(delivery_date)), 300)*300)
ORDER BY count DESC
LIMIT 10000;
```

In My case I did check the ECS docker container and the EC2 instance the task (container) runs on.

**EC2 machine**:

```
[ec_user@1.2.3.4]$date
Tue Dec 22 16:31:07 UTC 2020
[ec2-user@1.2.3.4]$ echo $TZ

[ec2-user@ip-1-2-3-4]$ date +'%:z %Z'
+00:00 UTC
[ec2-user@ip-1-2-3-4]$ cat /etc/timezone
cat: /etc/timezone: No such file or directory
[ec2-user@ip-1-2-3-4]$ cat /etc/timezone
cat: /etc/timezone: No such file or directory
[ec2-user@ip-1-2-3-4]$ timedatectl
      Local time: Tue 2020-12-22 16:40:47 UTC
  Universal time: Tue 2020-12-22 16:40:47 UTC
        RTC time: Tue 2020-12-22 16:40:42
       Time zone: n/a (UTC, +0000)
     NTP enabled: yes
NTP synchronized: no
 RTC in local TZ: no
      DST active: n/a
```

**ECS container**:

```
/ # date
Tue Dec 22 16:43:53 UTC 2020
/ # echo $TZ

/ # date +'%:z %Z'

/ # cat /etc/timezone
cat: can't open '/etc/timezone': No such file or directory
```

**Clickhouse DB:**

```
SELECT now();
2020-12-22T16:50:32
```

**Superset MySQL (AWS RDS):**

```
SELECT now();
2020-12-22T16:52:27
```

**https://time.is/de/UTC**

```
16:57:01
```

**Save a query in SQLLab**

```
created_on
2020-12-22T16:59:03
```

Data is UTC based as well. So where do I need to change this? It seems there's another setting or configuration missing.

I have the following setup:

- Apache Superset 0.37 on AWS ECS
- Superset ConfigDB: AWS RDS
- Fact DB: Clickhouse DB 20.7
- Driver: clickhouse-sqlalchemy (native mode)